# Parse database receiving corrupted audio files with Android Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform

This code is working perfectly as expected on iOS, and appears to work perfectly on the Android device, but on inspecting the database, all the recordings made on an android phone wind up on the database with a size of 0kb and won't play. So they are corrupted or something...

```js
        var options = { limit: 1, duration: 10 };
        console.log(options);
        $cordovaCapture.captureAudio(options).then(function(audioData) 
        {
          //  alert("Record was success");
         
            console.log("in $cordovaCapture.captureAudio function")
            var path = audioData[0].fullPath;
            console.log(path + "   var path")
            window.localStorage['tmpRecord'] = path;
            console.log(window.localStorage['tmpRecord'] + " window.localStorage")
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);

            function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                console.log(fileSystem + " gotFS function");
                fileSystem.root.getFile(audioData[0].name, {create : true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
            }

            function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                console.log("gotFileEntry:" + fileEntry);
                fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
            }

            function gotFile(file){
                console.log("gotFile");
                //readBinaryString(file);
                readArrayBuffer(file);
            }

            /* GET TIMESTAMP */
            function checkTime(i) {
                if (i < 10) {
                    i = "0" + i;
                }
                return i;
            }

            function getHHMMSS(){
                var today = new Date();
                var h = today.getHours();
                var m = today.getMinutes();
                var s = today.getSeconds();
                // add a zero in front of numbers<10
                m = checkTime(m);
                s = checkTime(s);
                return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            }
       
            /************* SAVE THE FILE *************/
            function readArrayBuffer(file){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                console.log(reader + "   var reader is here");
                reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                    console.log("readArrayBuffer : " + evt.target.result);
                    
                    var ParseFile = new Parse.File("recording.wav", file);
                    console.log(ParseFile + "    var Parsefile is here")
                    ParseFile.save().then(function() 
                    {
                       // alert('Inside ParseFile.save()');
                        var myPoint = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: $scope.currentLiveLatitude, longitude: $scope.currentLiveLongitude});
                        console.log(myPoint)
                        var recording = new Parse.Object("Recordings");
                        console.log(recording)
                        /*Set variables */
                        recording.set("username", "Sasstic Plurgery");
                        recording.set("latitude", $scope.currentLiveLatitude.toString());
                        recording.set("longitude", $scope.currentLiveLongitude.toString());
                        recording.set("geoLocation", myPoint);
                        recording.set("dateTime", getHHMMSS());
                        recording.set("recording", ParseFile);

                        /*Save to server */
                        recording.save({
                            success: function(recording) {
                                alert("Recordings saved successfully");
                            },
                            error: function(recording, error){
                                alert("Recordings save failure, error = " + error + " error msg: " + error.message);
                            }
                        });
                    },function(error) {
                        alert("File save failure");
                    });
                }
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }
```

What's going on here? I googled and googled, and didn't find any answers. Googled at least 3 pages, and a couple different queries too.

UPDATE - so I figured out how to check if the file is there in the first place using this code:

```js
            function checkIfFileExists(path){
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
                    fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
                }, getFSFail); //of requestFileSystem
            }
            function fileExists(fileEntry){
                alert("File " + fileEntry.fullPath + " exists!");
            }
            function fileDoesNotExist(){
                alert("file does not exist");
            }
            function getFSFail(evt) {
                console.log(evt.target.error.code);
            }
            checkIfFileExists(audioData[0].name);
```

And it returns false. So the file is being created by the Android Voice Recorder, but it supposedly does not exist within the file system, which is confusing since the file path in audioData[0].fullPath seems to be right, since I can see a file in Android File Transfer with that name under the Sounds directory.

Another explanation I came up with is that the livereload debugging mode of ionic run android -l supposedly uses the computer for all the file hosting, while just using the device as an interface. So maybe that has something to do with it - but when I do a plain ionic build and ionic or cordova run, I'm getting the same error with the uploaded file.

Right now the solution seems to be finding out where the default voice recorder saves its files and directing the path to refer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem - the {create: true} parameter was causing a file to be made no matter what, thereby making a file with 0 kb. But still have the pathing problem. Have to figure out how to go from the fileSystem root of the app up a couple directories then back down one to the /Sounds folder, where the default voice recorder stores its stuff. Unless there is another plugin that can do the recording for us.